# вставка DateTime в БД Clickhouse без изменений

Tags: datetime, timezone, clickhouse

Есть БД Clickhouse.
В БД таблица с полем типа DateTime без указания timezone (пробовал указывать 'UTC' без разницы).
Вставляю данные из Oracle c помощью datax (etl от alibaba ) в clickhouse. В итоге получаю разные даты в Oracle и clickhouse.
Как вставлять чтобы дата не менялась?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась не в Clickhouse!
Проблема была в DataX, надо было в конфиге ../datax/conf/core.json
изменить timezone. Так как DataX китайский продукт то разобрался не сразу.